# garbage collector Issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection, scjp

this question is like my previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182383/when-an-object-is-eligible-for-a-garbage-collector) 
Given:

```
3. interface Animal { void makeNoise(); }
4. class Horse implements Animal {
5.   Long weight = 1200L;
6.   public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("whinny"); }
7.  }
8.  public class Icelandic extends Horse {
9.   public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("vinny"); }
10.  public static void main(String[] args) {
11.    Icelandic i1 = new Icelandic();
12.    Icelandic i2 = new Icelandic();
13.    Icelandic i3 = new Icelandic();
14.    i3 = i1; i1 = i2; i2 = null; i3 = i1;
15.  }
16. }
```

When line 14 is reached, how many objects are eligible for the garbage collector?

> A. 0
>
> B. 1
>
> C. 2
>
> D. 3
>
> E. 4
>
> F. 6

I chose A but the right answer is E, but I don't know Why?

Comment: I don't see how it could be `E`, since you're only creating three object instances (ignoring any objects that might be created inside of the `Icelandic` constructor).  Unless they're saying `args` is also a candidate for garbage collection on the grounds that `main()` is about to return and terminate the program.

Comment: @vainolo it's in between 13 and 15. :-)

Comment: Notice the `weight` field. Its type is `Long` so it's an object as well. Two instances of `Icelandic` are garbage collected and so are their weights.

Comment: if "when line 14 is reached" means line 14 is not executed, then 0. if it means otherwise, then 4.

Comment: @Tom - Fair enough, but isn't that essentially double counting?  I think by pointing out that an instance of `Icelandic` will be garbage collected, it's implied that all of that instance's fields will be collected as well.  Though the author of the question seems to disagree.

Comment: It's a tricky exam. It actually gets even more complicated because the garbage collection of these fields actually depends on the `Long` values in question. Like Tomasz Nurkiewicz said in his answer, if they're small enough to fit in the `LongCache`, they are reused. Look at line *546* in [the source of java.lang.Long](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Long.java.html). You can also read [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching) for an explanation.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271895/garbage-collection-mock-for-the-ocpjp-exam with little modifications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's call the three `Icelandic` objects created in `main` as `A`, `B` and `C`.

Initialy

- `i1=A`, `i2=B` and `i3=C`;

After `i3 = i1`

- `i1=A`, `i2=B` and `i3=A`;

After `i1 = i2`

- `i1=B`, `i2=B` and `i3=A`;

After `i2 = null`:

- `i1=B`, `i2=null` and `i3=A`;

After `i3 = i1`

- `i1=B`, `i2=null` and `i3=B`

In line 14, there are standing references to only `B` object of type `Icelandic`. `A` and `C` are lost in the running program.

Each `Icelandic` object that is lost gives garbage collector two objects to collect, ie. the `Icelandic` object itself and the `Long` object within every `Icelandic`, which make the total number of garbage collected objects *4*.

Since `makeNoise` methods are never called, they do not change the outcome.

Comment: Would it make any difference if `makeNoise()` methods **were** called?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: It depends on the implementation of `System.out.println`.

Comment: i think that i'm missing a rule, i thought that when this assignment executed i1 = i2, i1 will refer to both A & B, but that seems to be wrong, is it true that when that ass. executed i1 won't longer refers to A and refers only to B??

Comment: @Eslam: Yes, that's correct. A reference will always point to one and only one object. When you say `i1=x`; `i1` will no longer point to whatever it was pointing before the assignment, it will point to the object that is also pointed by `x`.

Comment: @junjanes: you are right, `System.out.println()` is free to create as many objects as it wants, +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, after all assignments in the end `i1` and `i3` point to the second object while `i2` points to `null`. This means two `Icelandic` objects are eligible for GC.

Each `Icelandic` object contains one `Long` which makes 4 objects eligible for GC in total. Interestingly if the constant was `12L`, the answer would be: `2` due to `Long` internal constant cache. Also note that `"whinny"` and `"vinny"` are from the constant pool and won't be garbage collected.

Once you leave the scope where all `i1`, `i2` and `i3` are declared, remaining two objects are eligible for GC as well.